# android applications

Tags: android

in my application i want to create a shortcut (a button), to another application but i want the user to be able to select which application he wants...
So how do i access a list of all the installed applications and how do i create an intent to start any one of those applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a chooser... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER